# Fatal signal 11 Error in android

Tags: android, memory-management, media-player, fatal-error

I am facing the error "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 3776 (ala.application)". I don't know the reason behind this. How can i resolve it? I am not using NDK.

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries that might involve native code? Can you reproduce this crash on an SDK emulator, or across devices from multiple manufacturers?

Comment: Hey brother are you using genymotion simulator?

Comment: This issue comes in Nexus 4 and Sony Xperia C. I am using only crashlytics.

Comment: @RavindMaurya I am just testing on device not on emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your all suggestions. I resolved it by release the memory in onDestroy() method of an activity.